# Facebook share button to post on a group that I belong to

Tags: facebook, button, share

I have the idea to create a Facebook like button that allows user to post blog entries from my website on their pinboard or (and this is the tricky part) on one of their Facebook groups that their belongs to.

So my first question is, is this possible at all?

The Idea is that a user can login on my page with facebook login and then when he founds something to share, he could decide to share it on is pinboard or a group that he belongs to.

I couldn't find something helpful on google, so I thought perhaps here in stackoverflow someone has some experience about the creation of such a function.

I'm very thankful for your help and answers

Answer (score 0):

A "Like Button" is only there to "Like" something, as the name says. If you want to be able to share something in a group, use the sharer.php: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2F

You can just open this with JavaScript (window.open) when you click on any button/div/whatever and select "In a group" instead of "On your own Timeline". Since the user has to select a group or his wall anyway, this is the very best option. You don´t even need to authorize the user for that.

Comment: Ahh, you right. Sorry for the unuseful question. Sometimes I miss the wood for the trees. Thanks and have a nice weekend